# unusable partition after installing windows 7 after ubuntu (dual partition)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, partitioning

I had the following configurations (taken after installing windows) [image]

after I installed windows 7, I can't access "data drive" or "virtual drive" from windows or from ubunut live cd.

I also tried fixing MBR using the process described [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) here, but that also fails.

Help please I have lots of valuable data on "Data drive".

Thanks,

Comment: as you can see there is some thing that seems wrong in the picture, its saying Partition type is "W95 FAT32" but the type is "EXT 4". something seems messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot read ext4 partitions, so that is normal.

As for the partition type it is indeed suspicious, if you are very certain it is supposed to be a linux partition, go ahead to change the partition type and mount it.

Also, it would more helpful if you can post the commands you tried in the terminal window as well as the output you received.

Comment: I think the partition type was a fat32... I reformatted them to fat32 so that when i install windows it could be accessible. please tell me how to change type?

Comment: okay, were you able to access the partitions in ubuntu after you reformatted it to fat32? When was the last time you were able to boot into Ubuntu? Was it after the reformat?

Comment: yep... I have been using the partition for 3-4 months without any problem whatsoever

Comment: Are you able to boot into Ubuntu with your current configuration?

Comment: okay that might be of some help... using the terminal i saw its mounted, but when i try ls into it, it say "ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /media/virtual/
ls: cannot open directory /media/virtual/: Permission denied
"

Comment: I was able to access it after using sudo.. :) thanks a lot for your help

Comment: no problem, I am still not sure what is your problem though. So basically you can boot into Ubuntu (without using the live cd) or Windows but you just have problems accessing that data partition?

Comment: No i am using the live cd of ubuntu... grub install is not working yet.. but that's not a issue as i have already tar the partition. my problem was that i could not access the data partition from windows or the ubuntu live cd.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i managed to resolve it, sharing for others who ran into the same problem. Some how the partition need sudo access to browse. so nautilus wont work unless its launched with sudo rights.

do the following

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nautilus /media/data/
```